# Get unique value of a user other than IP

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I am developing a PHP application, only used by our employees in 3 diff locations. I want a when, whom, where log.  I am getting only 3 unique IPs, since all of them using internet via proxy and chrome browser mostly. Is there any other unique value other than IP or Browser info? that should be record by javascript or PHP.  I know there is a security problem of getting computername or local ip, but please suggest and anyother solutions.

Waiting for your valuable suggestions

Comment: Use a cookie.  Nothing more to it.

Answer (score 4):

You could use session/cookies? But for something like this, you should really have a log-in sort of system.

Comment: Sessions are different and distinct from authentication.  If all he needs to do is identify different clients (note I did not say different _users_), the OP can simply set a session cookie to identify individual clients.  This is trivially easy and doesn't force the users to go thru cumbersome registration and login flows.

Answer (score 0):

You may consider using Google Maps Geolocation to find and store the zipcode:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/geolocation/

Comment: doesn't help - it's based off of IP address (or requires users to be on mobile client I guess?)

Comment: It looks like this requires information the OP is unlikely to have - https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/geolocation/#body - and involves non-trivial client-side scripting to implement.  This just isn't a feasible solution (IMHO).  Nor does it guarantee a unique client ID (e.g. if two users are connecting from the same wi-fi network, they'll geolocate identically.)

Comment: Hi...first of all I would like to implement this log since most my users have a simple password. I canot force them use a strong password now. Some users login with other user's ID in their system. I want to find and log it for future use.